# Filtering a SelectList based on a User's Role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When assigning a user to a certain project, I'd like to limit the list of available users to people with the role "Project Manager". I could use some help with the syntax because I can't seem to get the LINQ syntax right for the Where method.

Create Action (GET)

```
// This is the unfiltered version
ViewBag.AssignedToId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "FullName");
// Attempt to filter   
ViewBag.AssignedToId= new SelectList(db.Users.Where(c => c.Roles.Contains("Project Manager")), "Id", "FullName");
```

Create View

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssignedToId, "Choose a Project Manager", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
         <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.DropDownList("AssignedToId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssignedToId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
         </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting an error on the DropDownList saying

> cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.

Comment: Is `Roles` a collection of strings or a collection of `Role` objects?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the roles are just a string, although they have their own table called dbo.AspNetRoles with an Id column and a Roles column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my question is including this code in the Controller Create Action (GET):

```
var role = db.Roles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Name == "Project Manager");
var usersInRole = db.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => (r.RoleId == role.Id)));
ViewBag.AssignedId = new SelectList(usersInRole, "Id", "FullName");
```

Instead of :

```
ViewBag.AssignedToId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "FullName");
```

And then including this in the Create View:

```
<div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssignedToId, "Choose a Project Manager", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.AssignedToId, ViewBag.AssignedId as SelectList, null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssignedToId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
</div>
```

Substituting for this DropDownListFor:

```
@Html.DropDownList("AssignedToId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is Entity Framework you're using, you will notice that db.Users is of type DbSet, whereas db.Users.Where(...) is of type IQueryable. I should imagine you will achieve the desired result if you add .ToList(), like so:

```
ViewBag.AssignedToId= new SelectList(db.Users.Where(c => c.Roles.Contains("Project Manager")).ToList(), "Id", "FullName");
```

Comment: I get a red squiggle on the string "Project Manager", saying "Cannot convert from string to Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole", do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: @springathing it means that `Roles` is of type `IdentityUserRole` and you're trying to compare that to a string.. `"Project Manager"`

Answer (score 0):

If `Roles` is a collection, then I would suggest creating the list of `"Project Manager"` outside of the LINQ to Entities query.  Furthermore, create a `const string` variable to hold the `"Project Manager"` magic string.  This will save you from having to change that string in every location you use it if that string were to ever change.

```
public const string roleProjectManager = "Project Manager";

var lstProjectManagers = db.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Contains(roleProjectManager)).ToList();
```

Then create your SelectList.

```
ViewBag.AssignedToId= new SelectList(lstProjectManagers, "Id", "FullName");
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I would assume `Roles` is a `List`.

Comment: I'm getting the same error for the string as in the other answer: Cannot convert from string to Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole

Comment: No that isn't an option, there's only Count & IsReadOnly properties available

Comment: Which table in your database does `Users` correspond to?

Comment: In the Server Explorer I'm assuming it corresponds to the AspNetUsers table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159182/discussion-between-gtown-coder-and-springathing).